# Time difference between local time and server time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

My current time zone is GMT+05:30. & my time zone name is India Standard Time. If the current local time is 2014-03-08 10:31:09.0000000 then by using the below code what I get the output is 30 minutes delayed time. i.e. the time I get from server is 2014-03-08 10:01:09.0000000. How to correct the 30 minutes time difference so that I may get the time which is same as my local time. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong. And please help me clear my error.

```
string zoneId = "Indian Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,tzi);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current date time from server and convert it into local time in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279525/get-current-date-time-from-server-and-convert-it-into-local-time-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This code is already correct.  You may just have the actual clock of the server set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that it is just a typo?
`"India Standard Time"` instead of `"Indian Standard Time"`