# Get current date time from server and convert it into local time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc, localtime

Help: I have a server which is having time in GMT-07.00 hours. My local time is GMT+05.30 hours. I need to get current date and time from server and convert this date and time into my local time. I have tried many codes, but still have not found a successive way of doing this. Can somebody please help me out.

```
string zoneId = "India Standard Time";
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
DateTime result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, tzi);
DateTime cu = result.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime cur = cu.ToLocalTime();
```

I have tried all the above methods, still I'm not getting the correct answer. Suppose my current local time is 09-Mar-2014 12:51:00 PM, then my server time would be 12.30 hours different from my local time, ie subtract 12 hours and 30 minutes from my local time to get my server time. I need to get my local time from the server time. How can it be acheived?? Please suggest me some solutions.. Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: don't you get your server time equvalent of local time  if you subtract `12:30` from your localtime?

Comment: I want to get my local time using my server time. So when I try to add 12.30 to my server time using datetime dt=datetime.now.addhours(12:30); but still not working..

Comment: did any of answers solved your problem?

Comment: I'm currently checking it out.. I will tell you the result afterwards.. Thanks...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

no need to know server time zone. if the server time setting is correct you can try this :

```
DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now; // gives you current Time in server timeZone
DateTime utcTime = serverTime.ToUniversalTime(); // convert it to Utc using timezone setting of server computer

TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, tzi); // convert from utc to local
```

to check it locally , change your computer timezone to match your server. then run the code. I check and it's working fine.

***update:***

the first two lines can be mixed into one line as below . that has a better performance :

```
DateTime utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Comment: The first two lines can be reduced to `DateTime.UtcNow`, which performs much better.

Comment: @MattJohnson : you're right. I just wanted to show the steps more clear.

Comment: Sure, but if you peek into `DateTime.Now`, you'll see that by calling `DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()` you'd actually be doing `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Local).ToUniveralTime()`.  So it's not just about clarity, it's actually *slower* and more expensive.  In other words, `DateTime.UtcNow` is actually the direct call to the Windows system clock.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add 12 Hours and 30 minutes to your Server time to get equavalent localtime(assuming you have server time), you can use `AddHours()` and `AddMinutes()` functions to add the 12:30 hours

Try This:

```
DateTime dt= /*your server time*/;
dt=dt.AddHours(12);
dt=dt.AddMinutes(30);
```

Comment: Also the server time difference changes when the server at location becomes down, then the server loads from other area with different time zone. So the time difference is always varying..

Comment: are you able to identify the `Timezone` info from where the Server time is coming ?

Comment: The time zone is Us mountain time zone. with a difference of 07 hours from GMT. that is GMT-07:00 hours.

Comment: Your answer will not work, since I need current date, taking datetime.now and adding 12 hours and 30 minutes won't give the result for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

So you have the server's time, and you know the server's time zone? Then you can get the local time like this:

```
//Server: 09-Mar-2014 11:00:00 AM:
var serverTime = new DateTime(2014, 3, 9, 11, 00, 00);

var serverZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Mountain Standard Time");
var localZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

var localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(serverTime, serverZone, localZone);
// => 09-Mar-2014 11:30:00 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

If your server's clock is set correctly (regardless of time zone), then the first three lines of your own code are exactly correct.  The `result` variable contains the local time in the India time zone.

Simply omit the last two lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now;

 DateTime utcTime = serverTime.ToUniversalTime(); 

// convert it to Utc using timezone setting of server computer

 TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

 DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, tzi); 

// convert from utc to local
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the UTC date and time of the server is (SELECT GETUTCDATE();).  Try it.